Reducing repetition of column and object names in data.table syntax
Using data.table, I want to modify the columns x1, x2, and x3 of data table object dt. Each version of the code achieves the modifications, but repeat the object and column names in several places.
How can I cut down on such repetition? For example, is there a simple way to indicate .SDcols = cols_to_modify should be updated in place, without adding cols_to_modify to the LHS of the second argument?
Note I am working with big data, so I must use data.table over tidyverse because the former is substantially faster.
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

dt <- data.table(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c("apple", "pear", "banana"), 
                 x1 = c(2, 4, 6), x2 = c(3, 6, 9), x3 = c(1, 2, 3))

# Version 1
cols_to_modify <- str_subset(names(dt), "^x[0-9]+$")

dt[, (cols_to_modify) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = cols_to_modify]


# Version 2
dt[, (str_subset(names(dt), "^x[0-9]+$")) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = cols_to_modify]


My gut feeling is that Version 1 is about as good as you're going to do.

I'd stick with Version1. If you need to apply different functions many times over to those subset of columns, alternatively, maybe split the dt into 2, dt1 with columns A and B, d2 with other columns that match pattern. Then work on full dt2 without SD.

data.table#795 is a discussion about dt[, names(.SD) := ..., .SDcols = ...] or just dt[, .SD := ..., .SDcols=...], and it is currently third on the master list of most-requested issues. I'm inferring that the checkmark next to it suggests that it is in-the-works, either "approved" or PR-pending (though I could not find it). I know there have been some recent reorg in their devs to try to catch up on issues, the main maintainer has been unable for many reasons.

As @r2evans suggests, names(.SD):= is implemented in data.table 15.99 (the current development version). Using that version, you can do: dt[, names(.SD):=lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = !is.character()]

I didn't realize it had been implemented, hooray! Thanks @langtang ... the next question is when they'll be able to release it ... I think it took 3 years to go from 1.14 to 1.15, for many (plausible yet frustrating) reasons.

A possible alternative:
convert_cols <- function(dt, cols, fun) {
  for (col in cols) set(dt, j = col, value = fun(dt[[col]]))
}

convert_cols(dt, cols_to_modify, fun = as.character)

